# JPA query ManyToOne Exception

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have the following entity class (excerpt):

```
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Orphans.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM ReferencePeak c WHERE c.libraryPeak IS EMPTY")})
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Entity(name = "ReferencePeak")
public class ReferencePeakEntity extends PeakEntity {

    private final ObjectProperty<LibraryPeakEntity> libraryPeak = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final ObjectProperty<SampleEntity> sample = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ReferencePeakEntity() {

    }   

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = LibraryPeakEntity.class)
    public final LibraryPeakEntity getLibraryPeak() {
    return this.libraryPeakProperty().get();
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    public final SampleEntity getSample() {
    return this.sampleProperty().get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<LibraryPeakEntity> libraryPeakProperty() {
    return this.libraryPeak;
    }

    public final void setLibraryPeak(final LibraryPeakEntity libraryPeak) {
    this.libraryPeakProperty().set(libraryPeak);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<SubstanceEntity> substanceProperty() {
    return this.substance;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    public final SubstanceEntity getSubstance() {
    return this.substanceProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setSubstance(final SubstanceEntity substance) {
    this.substanceProperty().set(substance);
    }

}
```

The named query "Orphans.findAll" throws the following Exception:

"The collection-valued path 'c.libraryPeak' must resolve to an association field."

I would like to query for all entities, that do not have any 'libraryPeak' set, i.e, where `getLibraryPeak()` will return `null`.

Comment: Then the where clause should be `WHERE c.libraryPeak IS NULL`. is empty is used to check that a collection is empty.

Comment: Not sure I'll be able to help, but you should post the code causing the exception, and the complete stack trace of the exception, in the question. You should also specify, in the tags, what your JPA provider is. I'm also not sure what those ObjectProperty objects are. Why don't you use POJOs, with fields of type LibraryPeakEntity and SampleEntity?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work with `IS NULL`, verifying right now.. I use javafx.beans.property.* to use change listeners. Thats also the reason why I need to use AccessType.PROPERTY.